# How to structure a JSP page when it comes to import CSs and JS?

Tags: jsp, web

I am starting a JSP project and I want to define how I would organize the CSS/JS imports in my pages so it doesn't become a mess.
I want CSS to be imported at the beginning of the file and the JS at the end, so I thought about this structure

Page:

```
 ______________
|              | 
|  header.jsp  |
|______________|
|              |
|  mypage.jsp* |
|______________|
|              |
|jsscripts.jsp |
|______________|
|              |
| mypage.jsp*  |
|______________|
|              |
|  footer.jsp  |
|______________|
```

The idea is:

- header.jsp: contains the head tag (including css imports) and starting body tag
- mypage.jsp: is the page itself, is has the include jsp commands, and imports the page specific css files
- jsscripts.jsp has the default JS scripts for the website
- mypage.jsp: again the page itself. Imports the JS files specific for this page
- footer.jsp has the footer html end closing html tag.

The only problem I see here is that the page specific css would be in the body tag and not in the head tag.
Is this the usual way to structure an JSP page or is there a better one?

Thanks!

Comment: Another problem is the Title. You'll have to pass it in as a parameter to header.jsp or your pages will all have the same title.

Answer (score 1):

I can share you what conventions I follow

```
<html>
<head>
  <jsp:include page="includeCSS.jsp" /> <%-- All of my CSS file includes --%>
</head>
<body>
   <jsp:include page="header.jsp" /> <%-- Application header --%>

   <jsp:include page="body.jsp" />  <%-- Body of the application. This page 
      may be further broken down depending on requirements --%>

   <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" /> <%-- Application footer --%>

   <jsp:include page="includeJS.jsp" /> <%-- All of my JS file includes --%>
</body>
</html>
```

Of-course what you follow may depend entirely on your requirements and needs. My convention may or may not be the best convention for you but atleast you can get a gist of how people are arranging their JSP pages

Comment: Hi, how would you add a page specific JS which depends on JQuery, for instance, in this structure?

Comment: No. IMO, page specific JS can't follow this convention. Page specific JS, as the name suggests should be only visible to the scope of that page. So regardless of any convention you follow, page specific JS will always be above it. But yes, if about 50% of the pages of my application are dependant on any framework like JQuery, I might add it to the includeJS.jsp and include it in the entire application instead of redundantly adding it on every required page.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know if I got your answer. Imagine you have the following code: $(document).ready(..... $('#myElem').val()....). This will not work if it is declared above the JQuery. How/Where would write this code so it is specific to the page and works?

Comment: Just make sure that your JQuery is always included BEFORE your page specific javascript